# How do I build using GCC 4.7 on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, makefile

I have a project that uses cmake that I'm trying to compile (MapCrafter). I've already done `cmake .` to make the makefile. I've run `brew install gcc47` to get GCC 4.7. It put it in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc47 for some reason.

Whenever I run `make`, it still uses GCC 4.2.1 at /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ that cannot compile this code. I can't find any option for switching the compiler that works. `make CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-4.7 CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/c++-4.7` still uses 4.2.1. I almost never compile anything outside of Xcode or apt-get, so I'm really ignorant in this area. What step am I missing?

Comment: Any particular reason to use GCC over clang?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Not really, just that everyone else is compiling this with GCC. I also tried clang anyway without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this worked this time and not before, but I used `cmake-gui` and hit configure. Then I set my C compiler to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-4.7 and my C++ compiler to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/c++-4.7 and made the makefile. I've already tried this and don't remember changing anything… Now, make is using the correct GCC.

Someone might have a better answer than this, so I'm not going to mark my own answer as correct at all.